# "On le voit voudrait garder" : signification

Tags: constructions, conditionnel

> Notre livre, on le **voit voudrait garder** le contact avec la réalité linguistique.

Tirée par l'avertissement  (p. iv) de la Grammaire pratique du français d'aujourd'hui (G. Mauger).

Je ne comprends pas cette construction des verbes (indicatif présent, conditionnel présent).

Comment: Are you  sure there is no comma after "voit" ? Then the sentence would make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No comma. Only after livre.

Comment: En l'état, la phrase ne veut rien dire. Soit le livre a été a mal été imprimé, soit tu as fait une erreur dans la recopie.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Pas de faute de frappe de ma part. Je l'ai vérifie.

Comment: One way of verifying this independently is that you can't have two finite verbs like that (certainly not present > conditional).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sentence as it is does not make much sense. My assumption would be that a comma is missing after *voit*:

> Notre livre, on le voit, voudrait garder le contact avec la réalité linguistique.

*On le voit* then just means *as you can see*.